# Java to upload file on share point

Tags: java, selenium, sharepoint

We have requirement to upload automation test results to share point server.
Can some one please let me know java code to upload file to share point.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: Please have a look at this link - https://blogs.sap.com/2018/02/01/consume-sharepoint-rest-to-create-a-file-using-java-sap-pi-udf/

Answer (score 0):

You may take a reference of following blog to see how to upload file to SharePoint using Java.

- [SharePoint Rest API to upload document](https://chintanblog.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-rest-api-to-upload-document.html)
- [SHAREPOINT 2016 ON PREMISE – JAVA APPLICATION WITH RESTFUL API CLIENT – CREATE FOLDER TO DOCUMENT LIBRARY](https://vectus.wordpress.com/2018/04/28/sharepoint-2016-on-premise-java-application-with-restful-api-client-create-folder-to-document-library/)

Comment: HttpClientFactory class is not written completly. I am getting error while running                                                Exception in thread "main" net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String
 at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:143)